# replace function removes formatting vba

Tags: excel, vba

[image]Why does this remove the formatting of the cell? I just want to replace a value but it removes underlines from all words within the cell.

```
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
    Next sht​
```

Comment: I can't replicate in Excel 2013.  Can you screenshot a sample cell?

Comment: @Comintern I uploaded a screenshot of the cell before and after

Answer (score 1):

Seems like in Excel 2007 the whole cell value is replaced. If the value to replace is between formatting, you might be able to replace it in the cell value XML:

```
Dim r As Range, s As String
Set r = sht.UsedRange.Find(fnd)
s = r.Value(11) ' Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet = 11
s = Replace(s, ">" & fnd & "<", ">" & rplc & "<")
r.Value(11) = s
```

Otherwise you can try this http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/524889-find-replace-loses-text-properties-formatting.html

```
Dim r As Range, i As Integer
Set r = sht.UsedRange.Find(fnd)
i = InStr(r.Characters.Text, fnd)
r.Characters(i, Len(fnd)).Insert rplc
```

Comment: I just tried it and it isn't working to keep the format. I uploaded a screenshot of how it is affected.